# MySQL 8.0.31 crashing frequently on Windows 2012R2

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm running MySQL 8.0.31 on Windows 2012 R2 64-bit on a AWS EC2 VM.

Frequently, the MySQL service crashes.  I tried to reinstall MySQL 8.0.31 and rebuild the database from a dump, but it still crashes multiple times per day, while a MySQL 5.7.40 database build using the same dump on another identical server runs flawlessly.

Here is an extract from MySQL error log:

```
 2022-11-03T19:50:35.155219Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.31'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2022-11-03T21:02:00.134125Z 16 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: dict0dict.cc:1222:table2 == nullptr thread 3400
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2022-11-03T21:02:00Z UTC - mysqld got exception 0x16 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0xb2c3422070
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff73131fa68    mysqld.exe!?my_print_stacktrace@@YAXPEBEK@Z()
7ff7304a9411    mysqld.exe!?print_fatal_signal@@YAXH@Z()
7ff7304a9153    mysqld.exe!?my_server_abort@@YAXXZ()
7ff731303a7a    mysqld.exe!?my_abort@@YAXXZ()
7ff73155c7f9    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7314b7abc    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7315636ee    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff731561ae5    mysqld.exe!?deallocate@?$allocator@V?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAXQEAV?$sub_match@V?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@_K@Z()
7ff7313fd64c    mysqld.exe!?set_compression_level@Zstd_comp@compression@transaction@binary_log@@UEAAXI@Z()
7ff73029349a    mysqld.exe!?ha_open@handler@@QEAAHPEAUTABLE@@PEBDHHPEBVTable@dd@@@Z()
7ff73031f59d    mysqld.exe!?open_table_from_share@@YAHPEAVTHD@@PEAUTABLE_SHARE@@PEBDIIIPEAUTABLE@@_NPEBVTable@dd@@@Z()
7ff73043351b    mysqld.exe!?open_table@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAUTABLE_LIST@@PEAVOpen_table_context@@@Z()
7ff730431ee7    mysqld.exe!?open_and_lock_tables@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAUTABLE_LIST@@IPEAVPrelocking_strategy@@@Z()
7ff730434595    mysqld.exe!?open_tables@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAPEAUTABLE_LIST@@PEAIIPEAVPrelocking_strategy@@@Z()
7ff730434a9a    mysqld.exe!?open_tables_for_query@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAUTABLE_LIST@@I@Z()
7ff7305681f1    mysqld.exe!?prepare@Sql_cmd_dml@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff730564d57    mysqld.exe!?execute@Sql_cmd_dml@@UEAA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff73046276a    mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPEAVTHD@@_N@Z()
7ff73045d581    mysqld.exe!?dispatch_sql_command@@YAXPEAVTHD@@PEAVParser_state@@@Z()
7ff73045c2b5    mysqld.exe!?dispatch_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEBTCOM_DATA@@W4enum_server_command@@@Z()
7ff73045d946    mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
7ff730289178    mysqld.exe!?thread_id@THD@@QEBAIXZ()
7ff731915b79    mysqld.exe!?my_init_dynamic_array@@YA_NPEAUDYNAMIC_ARRAY@@IIPEAXII@Z()
7ff7313105ac    mysqld.exe!?my_thread_self_setname@@YAXPEBD@Z()
7ff96c24f4a0    ucrtbase.DLL!_o__realloc_base()
7ff9749a13d2    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ff976215504    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (b2cdcd0030): {query text here}
Connection ID (thread ID): 16
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

The query shown in the log is never the same, and never on the same tables. CHECK TABLE doesn't find any problem.

I thought it could be related to interferences with an antivirus, but there isn't any installed on the server.

Does anybody have an idea what could be going on?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a `table2`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE table2`; maybe that will help us decide what to look at next.

Comment: There isn't any table2.  I even checked in mysql and sys databases.

Comment: Does your database have stored procedures that update multiple tables with update triggers defined?

Comment: There isn't any stored procedure or trigger in this database

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a very similar problem with MySQL 8.0.30 on macOS 10.14.6.
It doesn't "crash" at startup or when serving data to my web server, only when opening tables with MySQLWorkbench and on occasion in phpmyadmin.
It doesn't seem to crash on the same tables every time, but different ones and also sometimes moments later it doesn't crash opening a table that previously made it crash, so it seems a bit random, but the assertion error is the same every time.
Have tried a dump and fresh new data directory with import of said dump, no difference, have run check on all databases with no reported errors.

```
2022-11-22T15:16:05.229667Z 49 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: dict0dict.cc:1222:table2 == nullptr thread 0x700010616000
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
15:16:05 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x7fd43fd4b200
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 700010615ea8 thread_stack 0x100000
0   mysqld                              0x00000001012639ec my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) + 60
1   mysqld                              0x00000001006e4bcb print_fatal_signal(int) + 411
2   mysqld                              0x00000001006e4d96 my_server_abort() + 70
3   mysqld                              0x000000010125cc1a my_abort() + 10
4   mysqld                              0x00000001016c22db ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long long) + 395
5   mysqld                              0x00000001013ef1c1 dict_table_add_to_cache(dict_table_t*, bool) + 1281
6   mysqld                              0x0000000101413850 dict_table_t* dd_open_table_one<dd::Table>(dd::cache::Dictionary_client*, TABLE const*, char const*, dd::Table const*, THD*, std::__1::deque<char const*, ut::allocator<char const*, ut::detail::allocator_base_pfs<char const*> > >&) + 5920
7   mysqld                              0x0000000101400c41 dict_table_t* dd_open_table<dd::Table>(dd::cache::Dictionary_client*, TABLE const*, char const*, dd::Table const*, THD*) + 65
8   mysqld                              0x00000001014dc3d5 ha_innobase::open(char const*, int, unsigned int, dd::Table const*) + 3093
9   mysqld                              0x00000001001809a7 handler::ha_open(TABLE*, char const*, int, int, dd::Table const*) + 87
10  mysqld                              0x0000000100665ffd open_table_from_share(THD*, TABLE_SHARE*, char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, TABLE*, bool, dd::Table const*) + 3373
11  mysqld                              0x0000000100497f06 open_table(THD*, TABLE_LIST*, Open_table_context*) + 3238
12  mysqld                              0x000000010049d3a2 open_tables(THD*, TABLE_LIST**, unsigned int*, unsigned int, Prelocking_strategy*) + 2434
13  mysqld                              0x000000010049f9dd open_tables_for_query(THD*, TABLE_LIST*, unsigned int) + 109
14  mysqld                              0x00000001005ae1ad Sql_cmd_dml::prepare(THD*) + 317
15  mysqld                              0x00000001005aea7a Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*) + 266
16  mysqld                              0x0000000100553552 mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool) + 5794
17  mysqld                              0x000000010055080a dispatch_sql_command(THD*, Parser_state*) + 1114
18  mysqld                              0x000000010054f032 dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command) + 7506
19  mysqld                              0x000000010054fe2d do_command(THD*) + 525
20  mysqld                              0x00000001006cb3b4 handle_connection(void*) + 388
21  mysqld                              0x000000010173f73a pfs_spawn_thread(void*) + 314
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6abac2eb _pthread_body + 126
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6abaf249 _pthread_start + 66
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6abab40d thread_start + 13

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7fd43fde4230): SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `gallery2`.`g2_AccessMap`
Connection ID (thread ID): 49
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

Don't know how long this has been going on since I don't use MySQLWorkbench that often and this error just shows in the mysqld error log, which I don't look at that often either.

The only thing I can think of being a possibility is that I ran an optimize on all databases and that automatically changed some tables from COMPACT to DYNAMIC, but googling it I can't find anything that says it's a bad thing to change the table format or that it should have any adverse effects.

Edit: Well, reported the issue to MySQL and it turns out it's a bug that has been fixed for future release 8.0.32:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109193